# Apache Airflow freeze on initdb because of DAG code connecting to Airflow DB

Tags: airflow

It successfully creates tables with `airflow initdb` but freeze on step:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 08364691d074 -> fe461863935f, increase_length_for_connection_password
```

The alembic upgrade freeze because I have in my DAG this code

```
    session = settings.Session()
    conns: Iterable[Connection] = (
       session.query(Connection.conn_id)
       .filter(and_(
         Connection.conn_id.ilike(f'{CONN_PREFIX}%'),
         Connection.conn_type == CONN_TYPE,
       ))
       .all()
    return [conn.conn_id for conn in conns]
```

I use it to create tasks on the fly based on Airflow Connections with special prefix.

But Airflow runs DAGs code inside `initdb` command.
So my code lock table `connection` and alembic upgrade script cannot change it and freeze.
Deadlock.

As I understand I have to release lock in my DAG code somehow.
Reopen transaction?
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok when I finally understood the problem the solution is pretty simple

```py
    from typing import Iterable
    from airflow import settings
    from airflow.models import Connection
    from sqlalchemy import and_

    CONN_TYPE = 'fs'
    CONN_PREFIX = 'my_special_conn_'

    session = settings.Session()
    try:
        conns: Iterable[Connection] = (
            session.query(Connection.conn_id)
            .filter(and_(
                Connection.conn_id.ilike(f'{CONN_PREFIX}%'),
                Connection.conn_type == CONN_TYPE,
            ))
            .all()
        )
        conn_ids = [conn.conn_id for conn in conns]
    finally:
        session.commit()
```